# Can't connect to one particular WiFi network

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I can't connect to my workplace WiFi with my laptop, my OS is Windows 10.
But I can connect to my home WiFi with WPA2 security with no problem, also sometimes I connect my laptop to my android device hotspot which is open and restricted by MAC address.

I tried these things so far:

1. updating my network driver from device manager.
2. disable and enable my wifi from network and sharing center.
3. I also tried to connect using WPS and still can't connect.
4. resetting modem. It has both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz option. I tried enabling both and one by one, still no result.
5. Finally I set modem WiFi security to open and still can't connect!

PS. I can connect to this WiFi with my android device with no problem. My Laptop model is DELL XPS 13 and modem model is TP-LINK Archer MR200